# Are all bookmarks saved in Ubuntu Web Browser lost?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, url, webbrowser-app

During hours of research I regularly bookmarked some important URL's by clicking the star in URL field. But how to find the saved bookmarks back?

Comment: When you say the "Ubuntu Web Browser", do you mean Firefox or the other web browser installed by default?

Comment: No, it's a rather new good browser. "Ubuntu Web Browser" is also included by default in the recent Ubuntu desktop releases. It is a lightweight web browser tailored for Ubuntu, based on the Oxide browser engine and using the Ubuntu UI components. It is the default web browser for Ubuntu Phone OS.    https://launchpad.net/webbrowser-app

Comment: Oh that little thing... I hate that... I can't get it to download anything and the back button didn't even work for me! :P

Comment: It's still in its early stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Ubuntu Web Browser and click on the <kbd>+</kbd> at the top - right besides the opened tab.

[image]

Now you can see all the bookmarks you saved and open one of them by clicking on the entry.

[image]

You can see in this example the bookmarked Ask Ubuntu site saved in the ubuntu sub folder.

Note : The Web Browser app is under continuous development; this is version Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Thanks! Found the bookmarks! So one needs to open a new tab and then within that tab click on the second tab "Bookmarks".

Answer (score 0):

Saved in ./local/share/webbrowser-app/bookmarks.sqlite; i guess firefox can import this directly; export into html possibly by sqlite3 shell

Comment: Words like "guess" are more appropriate in comments and inappropriate in answers.